# How to skip few part of the video in ExoPlayer android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I would like to implement features like Skip Introduction, skip credits in my video player. I'm using Exoplayer and let's say I have a video of length 00:15:21 (hh:mm:ss), I know actual contents of the video starts at 00:00:18 and content finish at say, 00:14:12. I want to show a "Skip intro" and "Next Episode" buttons like in NetFlix. How can I achieve this?

Question on Exoplayer page Github : 
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with the help of ExoPlayer developers themselves I got a solution. Details are in the reference link I added in the question. Here is the summary :

Provided we know the duration of the skipping, we can create and send messages to Exoplayer and in the callback, we can implement our business logic such as making the button visible, button's onClickListners etc.

```
private class PlayerEventListener extends Player.DefaultEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(@Player.DiscontinuityReason int reason) {

                prepareSkipToNextEpisode();
                if(reason == DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION){          //when a video naturally ends it course and starts playing next video.
                    prepareSkipIntro();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            super.onTracksChanged(trackGroups, trackSelections);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            String stateString;

            switch (playbackState) {
                case Player.STATE_IDLE: // The player does not have any media to play.
                    stateString = "Player.STATE_IDLE";
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
                    //mPlayerView.hideController();
                    mediaControlsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_BUFFERING: // The player needs to load media before playing.
                    stateString = "Player.STATE_BUFFERING";
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mediaControlsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_READY: // The player is able to immediately play from its current position.
                    stateString = "Player.STATE_READY";
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mediaControlsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                    prepareSkipToNextEpisode();
                    if((player.getContentPosition() < 5000)) {
                            prepareSkipIntro();
                        }
                        //prepareSkipToNextEpisode();


                    break;
                case Player.STATE_ENDED: // The player has finished playing the media.
                    stateString = "Player.STATE_ENDED";
                    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    stateString = "UNKNOWN_STATE";
                    break;
            }

        }

    }


private void prepareSkipIntro(){

        if(episodeStartTimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()] > 0) {
            inttoBeginsHandler = new Handler();
            long introDurationMs = 3 * 1000;
            player.createMessage((messageType, payload) -> hideSkipIntro())
                    .setPosition(introDurationMs).setHandler(inttoBeginsHandler).send();
        }

    }


    private void hideSkipIntro(){

        if(player.getCurrentPosition()>2500) {
            skipIntroBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            skipIntroBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (player != null) {

                        player.seekTo(episodeStartTimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()]);
                        prepareSkipToNextEpisode();
                        skipIntroBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    skipIntroBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    }


    private void prepareSkipToNextEpisode(){


        if(episodeEndTimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()] > 0) {
            if (player.getCurrentPosition() < 1000) {

                remainingTime = episodeDummyEndtimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()];

            } else {

                remainingTime = episodeDummyEndtimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()] - player.getCurrentPosition();


            }

            creditsBeginssHandler = null;
            creditsBeginssHandler = new Handler();
            player.createMessage((messageType, payload) -> endEpisode())
                    .setPosition(remainingTime).setHandler(creditsBeginssHandler).send();
        }

    }

    private void endEpisode(){


        if(player.getCurrentPosition()>= episodeDummyEndtimes[player.getCurrentWindowIndex()]) {



            if (player.getCurrentWindowIndex() < (episodeEndTimes.length-1)) {  // no need of skip credits for the final episode
                skipCreditsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                skipCreditsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        player.seekTo(player.getNextWindowIndex(), 0);
                        skipCreditsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        skipCreditsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }, 5000);
            }else{
                skipCreditsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I have generally taken 00:15:00 as the end of the video content, note that if the user manually moves beyond that duration using seekbar, the message won't be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

From [Developer Guide](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html), you can use `ClippingMediaSource` API to achieve your task.

> ClippingMediaSource can be used to clip a MediaSource so that only part of it is played

To start playing the video from 00:00:18 to the end (**Skip Intro**).

```
MediaSource videoSource =
    new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(videoUri);
// Clip to start at from 00:00:18 to the end.
ClippingMediaSource clippingSource =
    new ClippingMediaSource(
        videoSource,
        /* startPositionUs= */ 18_000_000,
        /* endPositionUs= */ C.TIME_END_OF_SOURCE);
```

To start playing the video from 00:14:12 to the end (**Next Episode**)

```
MediaSource videoSource =
    new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(videoUri);
// Clip to start at from 00:14:12 to the end.
ClippingMediaSource clippingSource =
    new ClippingMediaSource(
        videoSource,
        /* startPositionUs= */ 852_000_000,
        /* endPositionUs= */ C.TIME_END_OF_SOURCE);
```

Or playing the video from 00:00:18 to 00:14:12

```
MediaSource videoSource =
    new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(videoUri);
// Clip to start at from 00:00:18 to 00:14:12.
ClippingMediaSource clippingSource =
    new ClippingMediaSource(
        videoSource,
        /* startPositionUs= */ 18_000_000,
        /* endPositionUs= */ 852_000_000);
```

You can find more info about the API [here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ClippingMediaSource.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Here skipping intro/credits is not pre-decided. It's up to the user. Hence Clipping won't be a nice idea. Please go through the reference link the question where I found a satisfactory answer. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The short and sweet way to do this is here.
below code clips the video at starting up to 13 seconds to skip the intro.
the video source is `HlsMediaSource` but you can do that similarly for `VideoSource`.

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = getSettedHeadersDataFactory();
            HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
                    new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(qualities.get(currentQuality).getQualityUrl()));
            ClippingMediaSource clippingSource =
                    new ClippingMediaSource(
                            hlsMediaSource,
                            /* startPositionUs= */ 13_000_000,
                            /* endPositionUs= */ C.TIME_END_OF_SOURCE);
            player.prepare(clippingSource);
```